# Fail Fast Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Firstly I'll explain my code in a nutshell

A config file is present which has a list of ID's. In a for loop these ID's are read one at a time and a list of JSON Structures are created. If everything goes well without any exception (e.g. entire data not being present) they are pushed into a database.

Coming to my question... For each ID, there are a bunch of business rules which are being executed. I've coded in such a way that even if any of the expected data is missing or if the business rules fails at any point of time I'm not inserting the data into the DB. The processing for that ID stops there, error message is written to a log file and then proceeding with the next ID. Can this be defined as a Fail Fast Design Patter is my question.

Comment: I'd rather say not. Fail-fast is usually reserved for situations when if you remove fail-fast checks, system will still work properly, albeit slower. If your database has the same constraints that you check for in application, then your case may be considered fail fast, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

As answered at CodeRanch: http://www.coderanch.com/t/663709/java/java/Fail-Fast-Design-Pattern

As is often the case the answer is "it depends". It depends on what you consider a failure.

Let's say that an empty config file is an error condition that you want to know about. A "fail fast" approach might be to throw an exception immediately after detecting the file is empty, thus halting the operation at the point of failure. The alternative might be to continue with the processing and end up writing no data into the database. At this point you have a bug in that there's no data in the database. Why is that? Did the database insert code fail? Is there a problem with the database itself? Did the file processing fail? Is the data corrupt? You're now on a bug hunt to track down the error and you have lots of possibilities.

For processing each of the ID's using some business rule. If the requirement is that all ID's are valid then to abort processing upon finding an invalid ID would be the "fail fast" approach. However, in your example you appear to be simply ignoring invalid data and only writing valid data to the database. This is not failing in any way at all, rather you are making a decision on how to handle invalid data where you simply ignore them. So no, you are not failing fast in this design.

The purpose of "fail fast" is to abort the program at the exact point of failure citing the exact cause of failure in order to avoid entering into a running but invalid state.